# Compiling pinfo on OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew, compile, autoconf, info

I would like to install `pinfo` on my Mac for reading *info* files, instead of using the bad looking elder brother `info`.

`pinfo` is not *yet* provided by *Homebrew*. Perhaps it will soon, when I will get this question answered. ([Here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/45203#issuecomment-150269090) the relative issue, on GitHub.)

The project web site can be found [here](https://alioth.debian.org/projects/pinfo/).
The source code [here](https://alioth.debian.org/frs/download.php/file/3351/pinfo-0.6.10.tar.bz2).

When I try to compile it, running `./autogen.sh` I get the following error messages:

```
atcold@AlfMAC ~/Work/Sandbox/pinfo-0.6.10 $ ./autogen.sh 
Cleaning autotools files...
find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
Running autoreconf...
Can't exec "autopoint": No such file or directory at /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 345.
autoreconf: failed to run autopoint: No such file or directory
autoreconf: autopoint is needed because this package uses Gettext
Something is bad with find's parameters (no big deal, I guess),
autopoint is missing, and brew doesn't know anything about it.
```

1. Something is bad with find's parameters (no big deal, I guess),
2. `autopoint` is missing, and `brew` doesn't know anything about it.

I also know that it was possible to get `pinfo` with *MacPort*, so there is a place where to take inspiration, if needed (not sure how to get there yet).
When I try to look at trac.macports.org I get a `403 Forbidden` answer :(
[Here](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=pinfo) is the link of almost the *Macport*'s package for `pinfo`, but I cannot go further.

## Still editing!

I'm updating the issue on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/45203#issuecomment-150269090). I will update this question later, as well.

Comment: I'm on mobile at the moment so I can't look up man pages easily, but it may be that `pinfo`'s `autogen.sh` expects a GNUish version of `find` that has a `-t` option, but maybe OS X has a BSDish version that lacks that. The easiest way around this may be to install the GNUish version of `find` (perhaps via Homebrew, if it has it).

Comment: `find` does not trouble me much... I got over many more steps in these past 2 hours. You can better follow it at the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/45203#issuecomment-150470391).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess people may be aware but `pinfo` is now available from `brew`:

```
brew install pinfo
```

If you're curious about obtaining `autopoint` on MacOS/X - it's available from the `gettext` brew formula - the catch is that it is keg-only which means it's not sym-linked to /usr/local by default as it can conflict with MacOS's internal version, however MacOS doesn't provide `autopoint` so one obtain it as follows - install `gettext`:

```
brew install gettext
```

then sym-link `autopoint` to /usr/local/bin:

```
ln -s `brew ls gettext | grep bin/autopoint` /usr/local/bin
```